# Running an executable over multiple cores using a bash script

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

Sorry if this is a repeat question and I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, but I am really struggling to find a simple answer that works.

I want to run an executable many times eg.

```
seq 100 | xargs -Iz ./program
```

However I would like to run this over multiple cores on my machine (currently on a macbook pro so 4 cores) to speed things up.

I have tried using gnu parallel by looking at other answers on here as that seems to be what I want and have it installed but I can't work out how parallel works and what arguments I need in what order. Non of the readme is helping as it is trying to do much more complicated things than I want to.

Could anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: It helps if you edit your question and show the first 3 commands that you would want **GNU Parallel** to run... then we can work out the incantation!

Comment: I just want to run the same executable in parallel rather than sequence. It is exactly the same every time it just takes around 6 hours to do 100 runs using the above code.

Comment: So you want run `./program` then `./program` then `./program` all with no arguments and in parallel?

Comment: Yeah. The program already has all its input arguments. I want to evaluate a variable in the program and how it generates each time so do to that I need to run the whole thing lots and lots of times.

Comment: You could just add `-n 1 -P 8` to your xargs command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in order to run `./program` 100 times, with **GNU Parallel** all you need is:

```
parallel -N0 ./program ::: {1..100}
```

If your CPU has 8 cores, it will keep 8 running in parallel till all jobs are done. If you want to run, say 12, in parallel:

```
parallel -j 12 -N0 ./program ::: {1..100}
```

Comment: That's perfect. I knew it would be simple I just could work out which arguments i needed and in which order and all the examples were trying to do more complicated things! If I wanted to limit it so that it only ran on 3 out of 4 cores so I could carry on working what would I change?

Comment: You could use `parallel -j 3 -N0 ...` or `parallel -j 75% -N0 ...` for 3 cores out of 4.